# db_delete on click on a link in module contents display

Tags: 7, database

I've made a module displaying a set of fields from the database.
I would like to add a "delete" link at the end of each row be able to delete the row in the database on click. I made it in my module with the following code :

The tests.module code :

```
<?php   

function tests_menu(){
$items = array();

$items['tests'] = array(
    'title' => 'Tests',
    'page callback' => 'tests_contents',
    'access callback' => TRUE
);

$items['tests/delete/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('tests_delete_form', 1),
    'file' => 'tests_form.inc',
);
return $items;
}

function tests_contents(){
$delete_path = current_path();

$query = db_select('form', 'f');
$result = $query
        ->fields('f')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $key){
    $output .= $key->id;
    $output .= $key->name;
    $output .= '<a href="'.$path.'/'.$key->id.'">download</a>';
    $output .= '<a href="'.$delete_path.'/delete/'.$key->id.'">delete</a>';
} 
return $output;  
}
```

And the tests_form.inc code :

```
<?php

function tests_menu(){
$items = array();

$items['tests/delete/%'] = array(
'title' => 'Delete',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('tests_delete_form'),
'access callback' => TRUE
);
return $items;
}    

function tests_delete_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$path = current_path();
$rest = substr($path, 13);

$query = db_select('form', 'f');
$result = $query
  ->condition('f.id', $rest, '=')
  ->fields('f')
  ->execute();

$testid = $result->fetchField();

db_query("DELETE FROM {form} WHERE id = %testid", $testid);
}
```

How can I make this db_delete function on click in my module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add path to delete your elements to `hook_menu()`.

```
$items['something/%/delete'] = array(
  'title' => 'Delete',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('mymodule_delete_form', 1),
);
```

In `mymodule_delete_form()`, use [confirm_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7). It will generate "are you sure?" form for you. Then, just write `mymodule_delete_form_submit()` to perform actual deletion.